# Protect php files and AJAX access

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

Since i start using AJAX in back-end I've got a security vulnerability:

I can't protect some .php files from direct access which in use by ajax with simple `define or die` statement. Moreover it is complicated by the fact that I don't use mySQL or any other DB system. The whole CMS is simple & based on files.

Thus I came up to the only one way I can secure PHP-for-AJAX-files: is to save session_id() somewhere (probably hashed) and send $_POST var with current session_ID to check if they match.

please let me know if there is a better solution? Is my method is good enough? And where is a better place to store the session_id var?

Comment: Since you are using sessions, add a parameter like `acces_token` in the urls, and check if its present and the value matches the one in your db; if not use `die();` or return 404 headers ( `myphp.php?acces_token=1d5sdf3dfs1dfsd5` )

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I'd say this is still a security risk. One may copy the `access_token` from one url and put it into another one to get access to the php file. I'd suggest moving to another framework that has routing implemented smartly.

Comment: Well i ment having a different access token for every user, and match only userid/accestoken combinations. For example, this is how most of the apis work